# Integrable Manifolds

Tags: integration, general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to understand why the line of slope *y* passing through (*x,y*) is an integral manifold. My intuition tells me that there exists a point in the slope field where the distribution cannot be defined, which makes me think that it *can not* be an integral manifold. However, I'm told that this isn't the case! Could someone please explain how to approach this problem/proof and why I'm wrong?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: What line are you talking about? What manifold?

Comment: The line of slope y passing through (x,y). I.e. Line of slope 1 passing through (0,1), line of slope 0 passing through (0,0), line of slope 1 passing through (-1,1), line of slope -1 passing through (0,-1). @OlivierBégassat

Comment: Are you asking wether this defines an integrable distribution of non constant rank in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: I'm unsure about the difference between an integrable distribution and an integrable manifold (or an integrable submanifold, for that matter). I was asked to find a non example of an integrable manifold, which, according to Spivak's "A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry" is the distribution of planes through points p=(a,b,0). Then, I was asked to find an example using the case posed in the above question. Thank you, sorry I was not clearer! @OlivierBégassat

Comment: A distribution on a manifold is a collection of subspaces $D_p\subset T_pM$ for all $p\in M$ that varies continuously with $p$, in the sense that at every $p_0$ there are local, pointwise linearly independent vector fields $X_1,\dots,X_r$, defined on some open neighborhood $U$ of $p_0$, that are tangent to the distribution (i.e. for all $p\in U,\;X_1(p),\dots,X_r(p)\in D_p$) such that $X_1(p_0),\dots,X_r(p_0)$ is a basis of $D(p_0)$. For a distribution $D$, an integrable manifold at $p_0$ is a submanifold $I$ of $M$ such that for all $p\in I$, $T_pI\subset D(p)$ and $T_{p_0}I=D(p_0)$.

Comment: A distribution is integrable if for every point $p_0$ there is integral manifold at that point.

Comment: So, essentially, a tangent bundle contains a distribution of linearly independent vector fields that sometimes form an integrable distribution? And in order to be integrable, every point in the submanifold must also be in the tangent bundle distribution and p(0) must map to the same point? @OlivierBégassat

Comment: Thus, in order to show that every line of slope y passing through (x,y) is an integrable manifold, I must show that the tangent vectors form a tangent bundle of linearly independent vectors and that p(0) maps to the same point in the graph of tangent vectors? Or am I completely off the mark here? @OlivierBégassat

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. "A" tangent bundle? The existence of "the" (tangent) submanifolds (to the distribution) is what it means to be integrable.

Comment: OK, so because these lines have tangent linearly independent vector fields forming the tangent bundle, they are therefore integrable? @OlivierBégassat

Comment: Please try to make simple statements and express them clearly, I don't understand what you mean at all. I don't understand how they could "form the tangent bundle", _the_ tangent bundle of _what_?

Comment: Apparently I'm not understanding at all what I need to do to show this is integrable. Could you explain how I should approach this, please? @OlivierBégassat

Comment: Do you know the Frobenius theorem?

Comment: That is the next part we're supposed to get to, but we haven't gotten there yet @OlivierBégassat

Comment: My bad, you don't need it here. You only need to solve easy first order differentiable equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the question, you are given the non-singular distribution $D$ on $\Bbb R^2$ defined by $$D(x,y)=\mathrm{Vect}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\subset T_{(x,y)}\Bbb R^2$$
(it is non-singular because it has constant rank, i.e. dimension, equal to 1) and are asked whether it is integrable. A *line field* is *always* integrable, this follows from the existence theorem for integrals to vector fields. For instance you could look at the vector field $X$ defined at every point by
$$X(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$
An integral curve will be a curve $c:I\to\Bbb R^2$ such that for all $t\in I$,
$\dot{c}(t)=X(c(t))$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}\dot{c}_x(t)=1\\\dot{c}_y(t)=c_y(t)\end{cases}$$
which means that the integral curve passing through $(x_0,y_0)$ has
$$\begin{cases}c_x(t)=x_0\\c_y(t)=y_0e^t\end{cases}$$
This gives you a parametrization of all the integral manifolds of $D$.